# overriden method first c++

Tags: c++, overriding

I am reading a book about c++ programming and there is an exercice that should be solved with virtual:

```
//Main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Employee.h"
#include "Manager.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

//Generates the choice of which type of employee we are working on.
int generate_type_choice() {
    cout << "1.Manager" << endl;
    cout << "2.Enginner" << endl;
    cout << "3.Researcher" << endl;
    int choice=0;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

void addEmployee(vector<Employee*>* v) {
    int choice = generate_type_choice();
    cout << "first name: ";
    string Fname;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, Fname);
    string Lname;
    cout << "Last Name: ";
    getline(cin, Lname);
    cout << "Salary: ";
    float s;
    cin >> s;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: {
        cout << "Number of Meetings per week: ";
        int m,vac;
        cin >> m;
        cout << "Number of vacation days per year: ";
        cin >> vac;
        Employee* e = new Manager(Fname, Lname, s, m, vac);
        (*v).push_back(e);
        break;
    }
    }
    (*v).push_back(new Employee(Fname, Lname, s));
}

void printVector(vector<Employee*> v) {
    for each (Employee* e in v)
    {
        (*e).printData();
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<Employee*> v;
    int choice = 0;
    cout << "1.Add Employee" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: {
        addEmployee(&v);
        }
    }
    printVector(v);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


//Employee.cpp    
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Employee.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Employee::Employee()
{
    Fname = "NoName";
    Lname = "NoName";
    salary = 0;
}

Employee::Employee(string f, string l, float s) {
    Fname = f;
    Lname = l;
    salary = s;
}

 void Employee::printData() {
    cout << "First Name: " << Fname << endl;
    cout << "Last Name: " << Lname << endl;
    cout << "salary: " << salary << endl;
}
//Manage.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Manager.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Manager::Manager()
{
    NumMeetings=0;
    NumVacations=0;
}
void Manager::printData() {
    cout << "Number of meetings per week: " << NumMeetings << endl;
    cout << "Number of vacation days per year: " << NumVacations << endl;
}
```

what i want here is to call the employee::printData and after that call Manager::printData
...
(Employee is the parent Class of Manager)
**i didn't put Getters and Setters to reduce the code and it is not a finished code so switch doesn't have only one case**

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried to solve this? Those are the two functions you want to call but where are you trying to call them?

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: i searched but none worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::` to call the superclass' operator:

```
void Manager::printData() {
    Employee::printData();
    cout << "Number of meetings per week: " << NumMeetings << endl;
    cout << "Number of vacation days per year: " << NumVacations << endl;
}
```

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't work right. It prints : First Name: NoName, LastName: NoName, Salary:0 then it prints the desired values but not in the right order

Answer (score 0):

You can call the base function from the derived function.

```
void Manager::printData() {
    cout << "Number of meetings per week: " << NumMeetings << endl;
    cout << "Number of vacation days per year: " << NumVacations << endl;
    Employee::printData();
}
```

Will print the `Manager` part and then `Employee::printData();` will call `printData` just using the `Employee` part of the object to print out the rest.

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't work right. It prints :
First Name: NoName, LastName: NoName, Salary:0
then it prints the desired values but not in the right order

Comment: @O.BelhadjHmida Works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80361969d3061070).

Comment: i want it to print 1 2 3 4 ( call base::print than call derived::print)

Comment: @O.BelhadjHmida OK.  Just cann `Employee::printData();` first.  That does go against what you said as you asked for *what i want here is to call the employee::printData and after that call Manager::printData*

Comment: it's a bit complicated here because i am not using diffirent objects classes in main i only use a vector<Employee*> which contains diffirent Employee child classes and using virtual which causes calling Employee::printData after each call of child::printData. i thought about making the call in child::printData of Employee::printData happens first. (only if there is another way to do that in another way, i am new in c++ oriented objects )